# Which data structure would have the optimal expected asymptotic performance when finding words with a common prefix?

Tags: data-structures

given the task of finding words which share a common prefix with a given word, which data structure would have the optimal expected asymptotic performance?

Multiple choice:
a) binary tree
b) hash set
c) sorted array
d) trie

Thanks!

Comment: Hint 1: one of these structure is also called a prefix-tree. Hint 2: check wikipedia. (answer: trie)

Comment: But if this is a question asked by a teacher, I would troll by saying that 'common prefix' is just a letter, and then I'd use a sorted array, find prefixes with a binary search, send a slice of sorted array. Cost of the whole operation is `O(log n)` (`n` the number of strings), and if any string that is part of the result has a length > `log n`, it is faster than using a trie.

Comment: Ok, I think the answer is sorted array then!  LOL, thanks for the suggestions guys.